# JWT Bearer Keeps returning 401 Status - Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The iss claim is not valid"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, keycloak

I am using postman and spring boot, I use Keycloak for the authentication service. I make the request with postman to the Keycloak server which returns me a Bearear token which I then send to the spring server for authentication, but spring replies that the iss claim of the token is not valid.

Here is my code

Class configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/genere/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/valutazione/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/carrello/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/film/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
```

Class restController:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user')")
    public String home(@RequestParam(value="someValue") int value){
        return "Welcome,"+ Util.getEmail()+" "+value+" !";
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```
keycloak:
  realm: demo
  resource: spa-demo
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/account
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
                jwt:
                  jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/certs
                  issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/
```

I start keyclaok with the command kc.bat start-dev in development mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the slash after the word demo in the issuer-uri.
The correct form was:

issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/demo

Comment: I wonder why you did not accept my answer (which is more complete as it explains how to find what miss matches...)

Answer (score 1):

Spring conf and `iss` claim must match exactly. Even trailing slash if any.

Put one of the Authorization-token you get from Keycloak in a tool like https://jwt.io and copy the value of `iss` claim in your spring config.